# How to get credential for BingSearch?

Tags: webservices

When I do `ServiceConnect["BingSearch"]`, it asks me to get credential for the service. When I click on the link it provided, it takes me to Microsoft Azure, and I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: It may be unrelated to your needs, but have you seen the [WebSearch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebSearch.html) function? It may be useful.

Comment: I know you need to subscribe to the Bing Search API to get a key, perhaps this is where you need to go first? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/search/

Comment: I do agree that this isn't straightforward or easy to figure out... Maybe contact support and see what they can say

Comment: Yeah, bad Bing. (Sorry couldn't resist...)